# SoapUI (pro) - automated retrieving access token

Tags: javascript, groovy, soapui

First, I have to write some "sosage around" to clearly explain what I need to figure out. So, please be patient.

In my TestCase inside my SoapUI project, I have test step that contains "send get request" step and "properties" step. Inside the teststep "send get request" I am requesting the access token

If I want to retrive this access token automaticaly, it can be done by Javascript (which I already have).

```
var userIdElement = document.querySelector("#idp *[name=userid]");
userIdElement.value = "123123"

var password = document.querySelector("#idp *[name=userpwd_page]");
password.value = "aa123456";

var button = document.querySelector("button[type=submit]")
button.click();
```

So, what is my problem?
I need to figure out:

- how to load a variable from properties inside my test scenario the JS variable to:

  ```
  userIdElement.value = "123123"
  ```

  It's common using syntax like

  ```
  def var_sql = context.expand("${#Properties#ID_SQL}")
  ```

  but this can be used only inside Groovy script.
  So, can be this done somehow in Javascript?
- And second thing is that if I want to retrieve AT, I have to click on "Get Token" and than click on "Get Access Token". But this is quite a problem when I need to do this automatically. So, do you have any idea how to do this automatically?

Thank you very much guys!

Comment: Don't you get free support with the pro version?

Comment: How are you sending GET request? A http request step? then you may able to use the same syntax as you mentioned, but you may use ${#TestCase#SOME_PROPERTY}

Comment: @tim_yates well, I am seeking information everywhere... :)

Comment: @Rao Hi, well, problem here is that syntax ${#TestCase#Some_property} isn't working in Javascript. Calling varialbe like that is posible only in Groovy, but not in Javascript. I am getting error:

`The following script is invalid: var userIdElement = document.querySelector("#idp *[name=userid]"); userIdElement.value = ${#TestCase#SOME_PROPERTY} //"9423752534" var password = document.querySelector("#idp *[name=userpwd_page]"); password.value = "aa123456"; var button = document.querySelector("button[type=submit]") button.click();  Error: missing ; before statement (scriptToValidate#2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `context.expand` from a script using javascript in SOAPUI.

For example if you add a property called `SOME_PROPERTY` in the TestCase then in you can retriever it using javascript as follows:

```
var a = context.expand('${#TestCase#SOME_PROPERTY}');
log.info(a);
```

As you can see it's possible also to use `log` object as in groovy, I add the `log.info(a);` due to this you can see the result in `script log` tab. See the follow image:

[image]

So the problem with your script it's not the `context.expand` is that you're missing the `;` at the end of some lines (as you said in your comment the error thrown by `rinho` which is the js engine is: `Error: missing ; before statement`). Add the missing `;` will solve your problem. So use something like:

```
var userIdElement = document.querySelector("#idp *[name=userid]");
userIdElement.value = context.expand('${#TestCase#userIdProperty}');

var password = document.querySelector("#idp *[name=userpwd_page]");
password.value = context.expand('${#TestCase#passwordProperty}');

var button = document.querySelector("button[type=submit]");
button.click();
```

Instead of:

```
var userIdElement = document.querySelector("#idp *[name=userid]");
userIdElement.value = "123123"

var password = document.querySelector("#idp *[name=userpwd_page]");
password.value = "aa123456";

var button = document.querySelector("button[type=submit]")
button.click();
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Well, the ";" was not the problem. I tryed your advice and I want to thank for it, but the place you entered the code snippet is not the place I need to use it.
I need to use it inside "get token":

[screen 1](http://imageshack.com/a/img633/5208/rxYqPi.png)
[screen 2](http://imageshack.com/a/img537/3046/GJGH9t.png)

As you can see in second screen, there is no even any "context menu" as it is normally in soapui... Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @MiroslavMajer ouch... ok I see now what do you mean :)... I can't try this since this options it's only available for a PRO version. sorry.